# .htaccess: dealing with .php extensions - redirect?

Tags: .htaccess

I run a hand-coded site with a bunch of pages with the URLs ending in .php

I'm working on a redesign running on Wordpress, with the URLs staying the same but without the .php extension. The redesign will be on the same server.

Could I edit .htaccess, so that any requests of any of those .php URLs get redirected to the new URLs?

What should I do?

Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: Try giving some examples of what you need, although there are many answers here to remove the php extension.

Comment: Sure. Old link: [link](http://keycommands.info/logic-pro-9-key-commands.php), New link: [link](http://keycommands.info/logic-pro-9-key-commands/) (with trailing slash)... I'd like to make sure the .php link will still work.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case - save some time and use a ready-made solution, like the `html5-boilerplate` developed `.htaccess` file.

You can find the source here - https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess.

Rewriting your Apache rules in a ham-fisted way can mess up how your static resources are retrieved, and you don't want that, so it's best to start off with something like *HTML5 boilerplate* and go from there.